# Copy outside file to destination with name from cell value in first sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

From inside one Google Sheet, I want to run a script (via script-attached button) that copies another, different, sheet into another, destination folder while naming the new file according to a cell value in the first sheet.

I'm currently able to copy the sheet I'm in to another folder with the script below but, it copies the sheet I'm in, not the one I need.

```
 function createManCopy() {

//from salesfile,that contains copy button, I get value from one of its cells to name the ManBlank file

  var fromSalesFile = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B3").getValue();

//finds the other file

  var getManBlank = DriveApp.getFileById("Other file I want to copy");

//sends the other file "manBlank" to destination

  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder I want the other file to goto");
 
}
```

I've commented only to help elaborate my intent for each step and I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable

Comment: Beg your pardon sir... my first post. The output came out different than the normal format I put in the editor. I dont see how to edit it now.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: My code does not work. But the plain text question seems straight forward enough. Is there anyone willing to help me on my first post ever?